# Rails web page shows more model elements that the inputed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have created a model called *Category*, which I have populated with data in the *seed.db* file as shown below:

```
Category.create([{
   title: 'Glutein-free hoagie with tofu',
   price: Faker::Number.decimal(2)
  }])

Category.create([{
  title: 'Hoagie with Pesto and Mozzarela',
  price: Faker::Number.decimal(2)
  }])

Category.create([{
  title: 'Hoagie with fried veggies and soy meat',
  price: Faker::Number.decimal(2)
  }])

Category.create([{
  title: 'Protein bread with sweet potato, carrots and vegan mayo',
  price: Faker::Number.decimal(2)
  }])
```

Now, I wish to display these results on my webpage so I connected it with the the categories.index.html file via *rout.db* as shown here:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :order_items
  resources :orders
  resources :categories
  resources :users
  resources :customers
  root to: 'categories#index'
  get 'home/index'
end
```

Despite that, when I go on localhost I see 8 elements instead of 4 with the other 4 being duplicates of the ones I have created. On top of that the duplicates have different values, which means that they are probably stored internally twice? This is what is shown on the page:

```
Categories
Title   
Glutein-free hoagie with tofu   29.84   Show    Edit    Destroy
Hoagie with Pesto and Mozzarela 54.11   Show    Edit    Destroy
Hoagie with fried veggies and soy meat  39.61   Show    Edit    Destroy
Protein bread with sweet potato, carrots and vegan mayo 83.89   Show    Edit    Destroy
Glutein-free hoagie with tofu   81.57   Show    Edit    Destroy
Hoagie with Pesto and Mozzarela 34.42   Show    Edit    Destroy
Hoagie with fried veggies and soy meat  16.71   Show    Edit    Destroy
Protein bread with sweet potato, carrots and vegan mayo 30.13   Show    Edit    Destroy
New Category
```

And this is the index.html file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1>Categories</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @categories.each do |category| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= category.title %></td>
        <td><%= category.price %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', category %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_category_path(category) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', category, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<%= link_to 'New Category', new_category_path %>
```

I apologize in advance if the post is too long, but I am not sure how else to publish the code, since there are many classes, which interconnect with each other.

EDIT: I solved this by deleting all data in the table by calling in the rails console *Category.delete_all*

Comment: You might have run db:seed twice. You can destroy all existing Categories using `Category.destroy_all` from rails console and running `rails db:seed` should fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you run `rake db:seed` twice and that why you have repeated entries with different prices. You can remove them safely and it should work OK.

Comment: thanks for the answer! how can I remove them? when I delete something from the seed even if I do rake db:seed it is still displayed

Comment: You should remove them from the DB not from the seed script. The easiest way is the delete them using "delete" button on the web UI. You can also use the rails console

Answer (score 0):

best way to do this

in seed.rb

```
10.times do
    Category.create([{  
        title:Faker::Food.dish,
        price: Faker::Number.decimal(2),

    }])
end
```

and then in terminal

```
rake db:seed
```

it will create 10 category data

Comment: now I see the 10 data created with this command and the 8 more I had before. Do you know where I could find the data and delete them?